# Laravel schema based on non-integer column

Tags: php, laravel, database-design

I have 2 tables `settings` and `invoices`.

In my `settings` table I have column named `amount` where I place integer value (it always will be filled) then in my `invoices` table I also have column named `amount` where the value should come from `settings` table `amount` column.

As we know relation columns are normally `id (primary key)` based so the question is:

If I make such relation in migration file is it valid (correct) or not?

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->bigInteger('amount');
    $table->timestamps();
});
Schema::table('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('amount')->references('amount')->on('settings');
});
```

The reason why I tried to make relation with `amount` column instead of `id` column is that I want this column always be filled based on settings amount column and avoid extra functionalities.

**The Catch** my settings table always will be included 1 row only so it actually not possible to get multiple rows or multiple amount column out of it.

**What's your idea (suggestions)?**

Comment: Your catch section is not clear. show your tables with dummy data.

Comment: @SachinKumar i meant in `settings` table i will always have only 1 row.

Comment: If you always have one row then really you need another table?

Comment: yes. they are included different type of data. the only similar data is amount column

Comment: Well, in that case, two different rows can have the same value for the amount column!

Comment: here is screenshot for you https://prnt.sc/rut9zg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211146/discussion-between-sachin-kumar-and-mafortis).